# Image isn't loading on page load in colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a little trouble loading this correctly as the image sometimes doesn't show and it's just a small white box instead, is everything set up right? - It was working but I can't work out why it's no longer working..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
            var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
            var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
            document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
            $.colorbox({width:"30%", inline:true, href:"#subscribe"});
        }
        });
</script>
<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="subscribe" style="width:475px;">
        <img src="<?= IMAGES_DIR; ?>/signup.jpg" alt="Sign Up To University Compare" />
    </div>
</div>
```

To see the live link please visit: http://universitycompare.com

Comment: Did you try removing `style="display:none;"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem exists because the colorbox calculates it's height when the image is not fully loaded (`height: 0`). So try to resize it when the loading is finished or give it a height value.

```
$.colorbox({ 
    width:"30%", 
    inline:true, 
    href:"#subscribe",
    onComplete : function() { 
       $(this).colorbox.resize(); 
    }    
});
```

Or

```
$.colorbox({ 
    width:"30%", 
    inline:true, 
    href:"#subscribe",
    height: "500px"
});
```

Comment: The second one worked but I had to set the px size for the width, Thank you TeeDee Jee

Answer (score 0):

At `.cboxLoadedContent` there is a property `height:0px;`

This is the problem.Try to change its value and will work.